# Need to output records

Tags: mysql, sql, select

```
select distinct type as vuln_type,
                (select count(distinct repoId) from vulns
                 where type = vuln_type) as cnt
from vulns;

repoId | type

1      | TYPE1
1      | TYPE2
2      | TYPE2
2      | TYPE2
```

Output I want to get

```
TYPE1 | 1
TYPE2 | 2
```

You understand what I want to do: if a `type` is exist in a `repoId`, we increase the number on 1 (the number of records isn't matter, means if there are a lot of records with the same `repoId` and `type`, it shouldn't affect on the result).
But my query doesn't work (work infinitely), may someone fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having to execute a subquery for every type, you could use a `group by` clause. This clause breaks up the query result (and any aggregate calculation) per distinct value in the `group by` list:

```
SELECT   type AS vuln_type, COUNT(DISTINCT repoId) AS cnt
FROM     vulns
GROUP BY type
```